# Why my Java project can't do a succesfully POST method for connect with my OrientDB?

Tags: java, rest, http, orientdb

I have a DB and need to do a REAL POST. I did a good GET and POST is failed (I don't know where) and don't have problem in compilation.

The POST method failed:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPost);
HttpURLConnection conexionPost = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conexionPost.setDoOutput(true);
conexionPost.setRequestMethod("POST");
conexionPost.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
conexionPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "216");
conexionPost.connect();
conexionPost.disconnect();
```

And the GET method that is ok:

```
  String sGet = "xxxxx:2480/query/mydb/sql/...";
    URL urlGet = new URL(sGet);
    HttpURLConnection conexionGet = (HttpURLConnection) urlGet.openConnection();
    conexionGet.setDoInput(true);
conexionGet.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexionGet.getInputStream()));
    String texto = "";
    String request = "";
    while ((texto = in1.readLine()) != null) {
        request += texto;
    }
    in1.close();
    System.out.println(request);
```

My code SQL for create vertex is something like this:

```
String urlPost = urlServer + "/command/mydb/sql/CREATE%20VERTEX%20V%20"
+ "SET%20certificateFingerprint%20=%20%27" + datos[9]+ "%27";
```

The answer of DB is: {"result":[]} and my DB is empty (obviously).

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you get some error during execution of POST method? Can you post the whole SQL query that you are trying to execute in it? Thank you.

Comment: Updated, you can see this now. I used with "Postman" and all is ok. So... here is not the problem =S thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing authentication in your POST request.

I've tried with this code and it works great:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


    public class Stack38089384 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String urlPost = "http://localhost:2480/command/Stack38089384/sql/create%20class%20Test%20extends%20v";
            URL url = new URL(urlPost);
            HttpURLConnection conexionPost = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            String userCredentials = "root:root";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
            conexionPost.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            conexionPost.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conexionPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conexionPost.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            conexionPost.setUseCaches(false);
            conexionPost.setDoInput(true);
            conexionPost.setDoOutput(true);

            System.out.println(conexionPost.getResponseCode());
        }


    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok thank you so much but... Where can i put my password? userCredentials is for my user only? or can put userCredentials = "user:password");? And... here is the response of DB: 200
200
-1
200
200
-1
500
500
500
-1
-1
-1
500
500
-1. Why (-1) and (500)?

Comment: You can see response codes explained here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html For username and password you can use user and pass of your DB instead of root:root

Comment: I think the problem is creating Edge (could be?) my command is: .../command/mydb/sql/CREATE%EDGE%20FROM"
                                + "%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20developerEmail%20=%20%27" + datos[5]
                                + "%27)%20TO%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20key%20=%20%27" + datos[0]
                                + "%27)"

Comment: Can you check if the edge is created or not?

Comment: You could try with CREATE%20EDGE%20E%20FROM%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20developerEmail%20=%27"+dato[5]+"%27%20)%20TO%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20key%20=%27"+dato[0]+"%27%20)

Comment: With the code provided by @Oleksandr Gubchenko and the command

CREATE%20EDGE%20E%20FROM%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20developerEmail%20=%27"+dato[5]
+"%27%20)%20TO%20(SELECT%20FROM%20V%20WHERE%20key%20=%27"+dato[0]+"%27%20)"
I get 200 and not 500    [image here](http://imgur.com/yygcPiZ)

Comment: Are you sure that the first query  SELECT FROM V WHERE developerEmail = 'yourEmail' and the second query SELECT FROM V WHERE key = 'yourkey' both return at least one record